# Angular 2 Singleton List Multi Window Data Sharing

Tags: javascript, angular, multiplayer

I have a multiplayer game , where new players are added to single game room lobby (which is just a list of current players) ? How can I manipulate the list for all connected players when new players are added?

I used a service , and added to the app module providers , to keep track of all the players ? But after debugging , i found out that the service is global for all components in a single window.There isnt a universal singleton service for multiple windows ?

Comment: websocket might help

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'real time' databases such as Firebase or Meteor.

Such databases allow the app to subscribe to changes in specific collections or objects stored in the database and react any time the data change.

If you register the players in a collection of one of such databases, your app can be notified any time a player is added, removed or any of his/her properties is changed.

Behind the scenes they use WebSockets as mentioned by Julia, but they can be found somehow easier to use.

Comment: I was thinking whether there is any way that angular can handle it ,

Comment: Not that I know. Angular is a client thing. What you are looking for is a sync mechanism between a central server and many clients.